# Scroll Problemas with Viewpager and Tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have an Activity with TabLayout and ViewPager. I want an activity with collapsing toolbar and three tabs, and the tabs contains CardViews, but the cardviews or the viewpager are not scrollable.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/city_detail_maincontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/city_detail_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar_pokemon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/city_detail_header"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/imagen_detalle"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarPokemon"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabsPokemon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpPokemon"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In the code I load fragments (with ViewPagerAdapter) and foreach tab but I can't scroll them.

The layout of the non scrollable content is this:
(I tried with the ScrollView but I couldn´t)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isScrollContainer="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTitleInfoPokemon"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:textSize="24dp"
                    android:text="Basic Info"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvPesoInfoPokemon"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitleInfoPokemon"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="Peso: 20kg"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvAlturaInfoPokemon"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvPesoInfoPokemon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="Altura: 1m"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTitleStatsPokemon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:textSize="24dp"
                    android:text="Stats"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitleStatsPokemon"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/hp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="15dip"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
                            android:text="HP "/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/attack"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/hp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="15dip"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
                            android:text="Attack "/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/defense"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/attack"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="15dip"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
                            android:text="Defense "/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/specialattack"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/defense"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="15dip"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
                            android:text="Sp. Attack "/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/specialdefense"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/specialattack"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="15dip"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
                            android:text="Sp. Defence "/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/speed"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/specialdefense"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="15dip"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
                            android:text="Speed "/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/total"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/speed"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="15dip"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:text="Total "/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/value_hp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="15dip"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
                            android:text="25"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/value_attack"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/hp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="15dip"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
                            android:text="74"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/value_defense"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="15dip"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
                            android:text="25"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/value_special_attack"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="15dip"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
                            android:text="25"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/value_special_defense"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="15dip"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
                            android:text="25"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/value_speed"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="15dip"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
                            android:text="25"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/value_total"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="15dip"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:text="25"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="3">
                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                            android:progress="75"
                            android:max="255"
                            android:padding="4dip"
                            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbarstats"/>

                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                            android:progress="65"
                            android:max="255"
                            android:padding="4dp"
                            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbarstats"/>

                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                            android:progress="50"
                            android:max="255"
                            android:padding="4dp"
                            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbarstats"/>
                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/progressBar4"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                            android:progress="80"
                            android:max="255"
                            android:padding="4dp"
                            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbarstats"/>
                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/progressBar5"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                            android:progress="45"
                            android:max="255"
                            android:padding="4dp"
                            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbarstats"/>
                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/progressBar6"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                            android:progress="25"
                            android:max="255"
                            android:padding="4dp"
                            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbarstats"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ScrollView` use `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` and your problem will be fixed.

When you have two kind of scrollable view It's recommend to use `NestedScrollView`, because it handle touch event better than `ScrollView`.
Also take look at [this](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/) example from googler which is same as your problem.

Comment: Thanks! Great example.

Comment: @FedericoBlumetto you can Flag it as accepted if helpful ;)